# Origins of "from the outside" (to mean from the beginning)

Tags: etymology, expressions, origin-unknown

I came across a sentence that went something like this:

> I wish I'd known about this from the outside - I would have done a better job.

I've heard "from the outside" used like this before a couple of times, though I've always had a vague feeling that it sounded a bit strange, like the speakers were misquoting another similar phrase. It always means something like "from the beginning/from the get-go", but I can't think of anything it could be a metaphor for. Maybe there's a sport where everyone starts on the outside of a circle and runs in...?

Comment: I think it means:  beyond the limits of one's usual work or responsibilities.

Comment: I've never heard this expression.  You're not confusing it with "From the outset" are you?

Comment: I'd take your example to mean *from before I got into it*. It does sound a bit strange, though. Needs more context maybe?

Comment: I've never used it myself, just heard it a lot. "From the outset" is very probably the "similar phrase" I was thinking of though.

Comment: The author of the sentence you quote probably misheard _from the outset_.

Comment: "From the outside" means literally that.  "From the *outset*" means "from the start".

Answer (score 1):

As both Chenmunka and Barmar suggest in comments above, the phrase that the poster encountered either was "from the outset" or was a misstated attempt to say "from the outset." Another mistaken rendering of "from the outset" is discussed in the EL&U question '[Are both "from the offset" and "from the outset" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178828/are-both-from-the-offset-and-from-the-outset-correct)'

As for the phrase "from the outset," meaning "from the beginning," the earliest Google Books match for the phrase appears in a [review of *Gratulatio Academiæ Cantabrigiensis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NH4CAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA449&dq=%22The+long+Hexameter+Poem,+of+between+200%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uuGaVbu-MMmoyATPsoOgCw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20long%20Hexameter%20Poem%2C%20of%20between%20200%22&f=false) in *The Monthly Review* (December 1761):

> The long Hexameter Poem, of between 200 and 300 lines, subscribed by Mr. Hardinge, of Trinity College, overcame our patience ; especially as neither the style nor manner, for a long way **from the outset**, seemed adapted to this festive hymeneal subject. Nor were the numbers and the diction sufficiently flowing and lively for the occasion.

A slightly earlier (and somewhat more common) wording is "at the outset," which has the closely allied meaning "at the beginning" and which makes its earliest confirmed Google Books appearance in Governor Shirley, "[Account of the Siege and Surrender of Louisbourg, and the Reduction of Cape Breton ; in a Letter to His Grace the Duke of Newcastle](https://books.google.com/books?id=wfoqAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA389&dq=%22at+the+outset%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5OuaVamfE8y2sAXWs4mACA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBzge#v=onepage&q=%22at%20the%20outset%22&f=false)," in *London Magazine* (August 1746):

> Horses and oxen could not be employ'd in this Service [moving the cannons], but all must be drawn by Men themselves, up to the Knees in Mud at the same Time ; the Nights in which the Work was to be done, cold and foggy, their Tents bad, there being no proper Materials for Tents to be had in *New England*, **at the Outset** of the Expedition.